# OpenID icon not displaying

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, login, images

The OpenID icon on the "manually enter your OpenID" textbox is not displaying. The link, http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/Img/openid-large.png, returns a 404 error. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. The correct icon is located at http://sstatic.net/so/Img/openid-large.png

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.